# Vue,js, Computing a property with v-model?

Tags: vue.js, v-for, v-model

I have a vue page that loads a bunch of `actions` from a database.  It then creates a table with some data got from the `action`, using `v-for`.

Here is my problem: In one of the table rows I need a checkbox that is `v-model`ed to an attribute, `action.weekly`.  Ideally, it will be a boolean.  But there are a bunch of `action` entries in my database that don't have a `weekly` attribute.  In those cases, I  need the checkbox checked, as if it were true.  Normally, I would use a computed property here, but you can't pass arguments to computed properties, so I don't know how to tell vue which `action` to look at at (I can't pass `$event, ndx` in to a computed property like I am doing below with `handleEnableChanged()` ).

Here is my code for the table:

```
<tbody>
            <tr v-for="(action, ndx) in actions" >
              <td class="pointer" @click='openModalCard(action, ndx)'>
                {{action.name}}
              </td>
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="action.weekly??" @change="handleEnableChanged($event, ndx)"/>
              </td>
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="action.enabled" @change="handleEnableChanged($event, ndx)">
              </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

In the cases where `action` does not have a `weekly` attribute, I want the checkbox checked as if it were true.  How can I accomplish this?

If there is a better way to approach this, please let me know.  I'm still a novice with vue.js.

Comment: Can you just `v-if` it?

Comment: As far as I understand it, v-if is only for optional rendering.  I want the checkbox rendered either way, but I want it checked if the v-model attribute is true or undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easiest to use `v-if` and `v-else` for this.. With that being said, I have also provided an example of how to handle this without `v-if` and `v-else`..

***Using `v-if` and `v-else`:***

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    actions: [
        {
          name: "first",
          weekly: true,
          enabled: false
        },
        {
          name: "second",
          enabled: false
        },
        {
          name: "third",
          weekly: true,
          enabled: true
        },
        {
          name: "fourth",
          enabled: true
        }
      ]
  },
  template: `
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(action, ndx) in actions" >
    <td class="pointer" @click='console.log(action, ndx)'>{{action.name}}</td>
    <input v-if="'weekly' in action" type="checkbox" v-model="action.weekly" @change="handleEnableChanged($event, ndx)"/>
    <input v-else type="checkbox" checked="true" @change="handleEnableChanged($event, ndx)"/>
    </td>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="action.enabled" @change="handleEnableChanged($event, ndx)">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
  `,
  methods: {
    handleEnableChanged(evt, ndx) {
      console.log(evt, ndx);
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

***Without `v-if` and `v-else`:***

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    actions: ""
  },
  template: `
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(action, ndx) in actions" >
    <td class="pointer" @click='console.log(action, ndx)'>{{action.name}}</td>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="action.weekly" @change="handleEnableChanged($event, ndx)"/>
    </td>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="action.enabled" @change="handleEnableChanged($event, ndx)">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
  `,
  methods: {
    handleEnableChanged(evt, ndx) {
      console.log(evt, ndx);
    },
    getActions() {
      let originalActions = [
        {
          name: "first",
          weekly: true,
          enabled: false
        },
        {
          name: "second",
          enabled: false
        },
        {
          name: "third",
          weekly: true,
          enabled: true
        },
        {
          name: "fourth",
          enabled: true
        }
      ];
      this.actions = originalActions.map(a => { 
        return {
          name: a.name,
          weekly: 'weekly' in a ? a.weekly : true,
          enabled: a.enabled
        }
      })
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getActions();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all items in the array to have an `action.weekly` property, then update your data when it is initially retrieved. You can then just use `v-model="action.weekly"` for all items in the array.

```
this.newArray = this.oldArray.map(item => {
  if(!item.hasOwnProperty('weekly')){
    item.weekly = true;
  }
  return item
})
```

Comment: If `item.weekly` is `false`, wouldn't this just change it to `true`? I think a better way to check for the existence of the `weekly` key would be to do something like: `if('weekly' in item){...}`

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. Yes you'd need to check it exists first before setting to true. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" :checked="!!action.weekly">
```

The `!!` operator will return `true` if the value is not undefined or empty